# Determining Day of the week using Zeller's Congruence in Java

Tags: java

I have been staring at my Zeller's Congruence program for an hour, but I don't know where is my logic error. Could someone kindly point out the error? Thanks!

```
// Implement the Zeller's congruence algorithm.
// To calculate the day of the week

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DayOfTheWeek {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter a year, month and a day
        System.out.print("Enter year (e.g., 2008): ");
        int year = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter month: 1-12: ");
        int month = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the day of the month: 1-31: ");
        int day = input.nextInt();

        // Check if the month is January or February
        // If the month is January and February, convert to 13, and 14,
        // and year has to -1. (Go to previous year).
        if (month == 1 || month == 2) {
            month += 12;
            year--;
        }

        // Compute the answer
        int k = year % 7; // The year of the century
        int j = (int)(year / 100.0); // the century
        int q = day;
        int m = month;
        int h = (q + (int)((26 * (m + 1)) / 10.0) + k + (int)(k / 4.0) 
                + (int)(j / 4.0) + (5 * j)) % 7;

        String result = "Day of the week is ";

        //Display the name of the day of the week
        if (h == 0) 
            System.out.print(result + "Saturday");
        else if (h == 1)
            System.out.print(result + "Sunday");
        else if (h == 2)
            System.out.print(result + "Monday");
        else if (h == 3)
            System.out.print(result + "Tuesday");
        else if (h == 4)
            System.out.print(result + "Wednesday");
        else if (h == 5)
            System.out.print(result + "Thursday");
        else
            System.out.print(result + "Friday");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int k = year % 7; // The year of the century
```

You might want `% 100` there.

Also, you're mixing two of the formulae. If you're after the best implementation in software ([as provided by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence#Implementation_in_software)), try this:

```
// ...
// remove j and k
int y = year;
// ...
// reformatted for readability
int h = (q +
         (int)((26 * (m + 1)) / 10.0) +
         y +
         (int)(y / 4.0) +
//       changes after here
         6 * (int)(y / 100.0) +
         (int)(y / 400.0))
        % 7;
```

or this:

```
int h = (q + (int)((13 * (m + 1)) / 5.0) + k + (int)(k / 4.0)
//                  ^^
           + (int)(j / 4.0) + (5 * j)) % 7;
```

You were (likely inadvertently) using the start of the second software formula with the end of the first one, causing the computer no end of confusion.

Comment: Also, there's no need to truncate integers by dividing them by doubles. Instead of saying (int)(year / 100.0), you can just say year/100.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz That code was copied from the question.

Comment: I know. I was responding to the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

`int k = year % 7; // The year of the century`

Shouldn't this be `% 100`?

Answer (score 1):

```
int h = (q + (int)((13 * (m + 1)) / 5.0) + k + (int)(k / 4.0)
//                  ^^
       + (int)(j / 4.0) + (5 * j)) % 7;
```

does not always give the same results as

```
int h = (q + (int)((26 * (m + 1)) / 10.0) + k + (int)(k / 4.0)
//                  ^^
       + (int)(j / 4.0) + (5 * j)) % 7;
```

but I appreciate and used your input, Thank you!

I also found this helpful:

//to output original year input (k<10?("0" + k):(k)), likewise month and day for format: mm/dd/yyyy;

```
String result = "The Day of the week of " + (i<10?("0" + i):(i)) + "/" 
//
+ (q<10?("0" + q):(q)) + "/" + j + (k<10?("0" + k):(k)) + " is ";
```