# java basic calculator to find the days of the week 7

Tags: java

I used  Zeller’s congruence formula to calculated the days of the week but i am getting the wrong days and need help figuring out what i am doing wrong and how it should look.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex_211 {
    final static String[] Days = {
            "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a year");
        int y = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a month");
        int m = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter day");
        int q = input.nextInt();


        if (m < 3) {
            m = m + 12;
            y = y - 1;
            }
        int k = y % 100;
        int j = y / 100;

        int day = ((q + (((m + 1) * 26) / 10) + (k/4) + (j/4)) + (5 * j)) % 7;
        System.out.println("That date was  a " + Days[day]);


    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you getting your formula from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining Day of the week using Zeller's Congruence in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390785/determining-day-of-the-week-using-zellers-congruence-in-java)

Comment: Your day formula is wrong. I'm uncertain where you're looking for that formula. I'm looking on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) under the subsection Implementation in software. Try `int day2 = (q + (13*(m+1))/5 + k + (k/4) + (j/4) + 5*j) % 7;` and compare.

Comment: @Unknown thx i didn't see that before

Comment: @ClarkKent Thank You! it worked i was reading out of this java book an it gave it me that first formula

Answer (score 1):

Your day formula is wrong. I'm uncertain where you're looking for that formula. I'm looking on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) under the subsection **Implementation in software**. Try `int day2 = (q + (13*(m+1))/5 + k + (k/4) + (j/4) + 5*j) % 7;` and compare.